# Composer + twitter bootstrap 2

Tags: php, composer-php

How I can add this repo https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/2.1-stable to my composer.json?

I tryed this:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require-dev": {
  "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "dev-2.1-stable"
}
```

but got error:

```
The requested package twbs/bootstrap-sass could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name
```

Answer (score 1):

dev-2.1-stable isnt in the package:

https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap-sass

its a branch in their git repo, but they havent submitted those versions to packagist (or the tags they have given on the branches arent valid for packagist to pick them up on its own: https://packagist.org/about)

Comment: The 2.1 version discussed here does not have a `composer.json` file with the needed metadata for packagist. If it had one, Packagist would offer it for installation.

Comment: cool, just a question for my own reference later: does packagist pick this up on its own when you submit from master/head, or do you have to submit each branch individually?

Comment: Packagist scans every branch it sees, and every tag. If a `composer.json` is present at the top level, it will be used. Note that the repo url, branch name or any other external information is irrelevant for detecting which package name is found - this info only comes from the `composer.json`. So you could easily confuse everyone by providing two or more different names in different branches or tags. On the other hand: If you are to rename the package, you will exactly do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you know they have a version 3 available. Also, do you not have Ruby gems installed? To install using their instructions add the package to your Gemfile, not to composer.

If you do want to install via composer, it has to be a composer package, which from https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap-sass looks like only version 3 and up are available.

Try using:

```
"require-dev": {
    "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "3.2.*"
}
```

Notice the 3 above, I tried `2.1.*` and it couldn't be found. `3.2.*` worked fine.

Also, incase you're wondering the `*` just means 'latest'. If you want 2.1 you might have to do it via Ruby Gems.

Comment: Then I think you will have to do it via ruby gems.